# Preventing system clock from auto-updating in Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, clock-synchronization

I'm working on a project right now where as part of testing I have to move the system clock to far-off future dates. There are two servers involved in the project: an app server and a database server. I've stopped the Windows Time service on both machines, which was the solution I was able to find the first time I searched the internet for an explanation/solution, and this *seemed* to have worked.

Trouble is, although the date stays resolutely fixed on the database server, the app server keeps resetting to today's date and I cannot for the life of me figure out why because the time service *is not running*. It's important that I stop this from happening as the time difference may potentially screw up the recorded dates of my client's actions on the app, causing problems in the expected data coming out of the database server.

Does anyone have any idea of what else besides Windows Time would cause the clock on Windows Server 2012 to reset, and if so how I can stop it doing that?

Comment: Are these virtual machines?  Is it possible your time is getting synchronized with the hypervisor?

Comment: No, they're physical machines but I remote desktop into them from a jump server I remote into from my work laptop.